# WordPress doesn't recognize submenus as <ul> so I can't style them properly

Tags: theme-development, menus, sub-menu

I'm quite new to WP theme development so I'm sorry if the answer for this question may seem obvious.

I'm developing a custom WordPress theme from scratch, and I'm stuck working on the menus. My header menu has some submenus that I'd like to style, but when I call the menu with the wp_nav_menu() function, the HTML output doesn't recognize them as submenus.

I mean, even if I built correctly the menus in the admin panel, the output I get is:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item #1</li>
    <li>Item #2</li>
    <li>Item #3</li>
    <li>Item #4</li>
    <li>Item #5</li>
    <li>Item #6</li>
</ul>
```

Item #4 and Item #5 are nested into a submenu under Item #3, for example, and I want them to be nested inside another ul, how they should be. 
I'm sure it's a theme related problem, because everything works well by switching to a default theme.

This is how I use the wp_nav_menu() function:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                    'container_class' => 'navigator' ) )
```

Maybe I have to add something in functions.php, but I really don't know what.

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you show me how you use the wp_nav_menu() function.

Comment: Sure. I just set the theme_location and add a class to the container. 

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
  'container_class' => 'navigator' ) )

Comment: @Oni-Link Are they nested *in* the Menu or are they Children under pages? They need to be physically nested under `Appearance -> Menu` to show as children, it won't pull children automatically.

Comment: Are you using a custom walker? Are you sure the menus are correct in the backend?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, yes, they are physically nested under Appearance -> Menu.

Comment: @s_ha_dum, I'm not using a custom walker and I'm absolutely sure menus are correct in the backend (they work perfectly with Twenty fifteen).

Comment: This may be moot as I believe you *have* to have this added to even add menus but, did you declare menu support `add_theme_support( 'menus' );` on init?

Comment: I am pretty sure Twenty Fifteen doesn't have a custom Walker so if you aren't using one, your menu should be using exactly the same walker code. Puzzling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a menu registration issue. That menu was readable by WordPress, but not completely, because there were no positions available. 
I registered again the menu into my functions.php file and it worked. 
Thank you all anyway.

Comment: Hi - if you could accept your answer it'll mark the question as resolved and help us keep a tidy site.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your array, have you tried setting depth to 0 or 2?

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
                'container_class' => 'navigator',
                'depth' => 2) )
```

Where 0 should be the default and allow unlimited submenu, and 2 would allow one submenu. I am not sure how this would happen, but if it works, perhaps somewhere the default setting for depth was set to 1.